# How to add a simple arc with D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to add one simple arc in the chart section like a circle:

```
vis.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50);
```

The provided [examples of D3](http://bl.ocks.org/1308257) are working with data properties but i would like to see it without any underlying data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

D3 uses a path generator for arcs. If you don't want to data-drive your arc just define the arc generator and add some methods...

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(45 * (Math.PI/180)) //convert from degs to radians
    .endAngle(3) //just radians

vis.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9XNz/

Comment: @KyleLahnakoski not sure why it's not working in Firefox, try with Chrome while I figure this out.