# Changing a Shapes position on the page D3/JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

linked div to js

```
<div id="svgpathSVGdata"></div>
```

Start of the D3.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var divElem = d3.select("#svgpathSVGdata");
```

Setting the canvas

```
    var svgcanvas = divElem.append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 800);
```

At the moment it is upside down and I wish to also move it more centrally

```
    svgcanvas.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d","M -200,0 A200,200 0 0,0 500,0 L -200,0") 
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("fill", "none");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a `transform` attribute to move your path and flip it the correct side:

```
var divElem = d3.select("#svgpathSVGdata");
var svgcanvas = divElem.append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 800);
svgcanvas.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d","M -200,0 A200,200 0 0,0 500,0 L -200,0") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(220,400) scale(1, -1)")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("fill", "none");​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QALqg/

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you say it's more beneficial using d3.svg.line() instead?

Comment: Actually in your case you'd need the arc generator `d3.svg.arc()` it depends on what you want to build with it. If you need to animate the arc then use the arc generator. Otherwise you'll be fine with the path.

Comment: Well essentially I would like to pass data from the database on to the shape in a form plotted dots etc ... I tried using the d3.svg.arc() but, couldn't get it to create a simple shape. Any help?

Comment: If you are plotting data then use d3.svg.line() is what you need, here is an example of the arc generator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074959/how-to-add-a-simple-arc-with-d3

Comment: Thanks again! Would you say in order to spilt my shape I would use partition?

Comment: I'm not sure, post a new question with the corresponding code (that's the etiquette around here).